# How can i create a trigger for my batch class i don't know how can i do it. [HELP]

Tags: apex, trigger

```
global class ModifiedDate implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
String query= '[SELECT Id,Name,LastContact__c,CreatedDate FROM Account]';

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope) {
    //code to do
    for(Account acc: scope){
        acc.LastContact__c = acc.CreatedDate;

    }
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    //code to do when the batch job finished
} }
```

### Heading

trigger AccountModifiedDate_Trigger on Account (after insert) {
ModifiedDate.execute(trigger.new);
}

Comment: Batch is async process , trigger is Sycn. try to avoid such triggers that trigger batches.

Comment: Are you trying to recreate the standard `LastModifiedDate`  field?

Answer (score 0):

This should kick off the batch job for you.

```
trigger AccountModifiedDate_Trigger on Account (after insert){
    ModifiedDate modifiedDateBatchClass = new ModifiedDate();
    ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(modifiedDateBatchClass);
}
```

Comment: n.b. - if many inserts happen in the same few seconds, many batch classes will get started and governor will be hit

Answer (score 0):

You can have only 5 running batch jobs. Just make sure the trigger doesn't hit this limit.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your batch query has no `WHERE` clause and you are defaulting a custom date field to the `CreatedDate`, it seems like there is no reason for this to be in a trigger. Simply utilize the `Database.executeBatch` method and execute it once. If you need to run it more than once, perhaps implement `Schedulable` as well. Just forget all about triggers for this piece of functionality.

Note that if you want to propagate this logic for newly created Accounts once the batch is finished, you do not even need a trigger because you can use a `formula default` whose value is simply `NOW()`. Or if you feel more comfortable with it, you could use a workflow. Try not to use code when declarative functionality will suffice!